# firestore sub collection removes change listeners when limit is reached?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

When data is added to a subcollection the real-time data snapshot is not getting triggered if the limit I set is reached. How to go around this?

I want the snapshot to display the last 25 newest texts. But since the limit is reached it just halts the function and I am stuck with the last 25 rendered and new ones don't show at all.

What is even worst about this if I reload the page to see if the function will render the new items after the limit has reached:

- it doesn't it simply shows the 25 created.
- it ignores any new items so the query is simply broken from that point up.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (_globalContext.focus) {
      let collectionRef = collection(db, 'Chat', docId, 'messages');
      const querydata = query(collectionRef, orderBy('createdAt'), limit(25));
      const unsub = onSnapshot(querydata , (querySnapshot) => {

        console.log(querySnapshot, 'triggered');
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.data());
        });
      });
      setChats(data);
      return () => {
       unsub();
      };
    }
  }, [_globalContext.focus]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the 25 most recent documents, you need to either sort on **descending** timestamp *or* [limit to the **last* 25](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#limittolast) (instead of the first 25):